# How to use nested loops in R to change values?

Tags: r, for-loop, dataset, nested-loops

I have a data set where I want all 1's to be 0's and anything over 1 to be 1's.
I've tried using parentheses instead of brackets.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(StudentDrugs)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(StudentDrugs)){
    ifelse([i,j] == 1, 0, 1)
  }
}
```

I get:
 `Error: unexpected '[' in: "  for(j in 1:ncol(StudentDrugs)){ ifelse(["`

Comment: Looping over rows and cols like this is highly inefficient. I suggest you convert your `data.frame()` to a matrix and just use subsetting if every column of your `data.frame()` is numeric.

Comment: @Antonio, could you provide `dput(head(yourdataset))` and expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't yet provide an example dataset, examples below use `mtcars`.

With base R, `rapply` and `ifelse`:

```
rapply(mtcars,f = function(x) ifelse(x==1,0,ifelse(x>1,1,x)),how = 'replace')

                    mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4             1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1
Mazda RX4 Wag         1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1
Datsun 710            1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    0
Hornet 4 Drive        1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    0
Hornet Sportabout     1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1
...
```

With `dplyr` and `case_when`.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% mutate(across(everything(),function(x) case_when(x==1 ~ 0, x > 1 ~ 1, T ~ x )))

                    mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4             1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1
Mazda RX4 Wag         1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1
Datsun 710            1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    0
Hornet 4 Drive        1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    0
Hornet Sportabout     1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this operation using data.table as well (please note I'm also using the mtcars dataset).

```
mtcars <- setDT(copy(mtcars))
mtcars <- mtcars[ , lapply(.SD, function(x) 0*(x==1) + 1*(x>1)), .SDcols = colnames(mtcars)]

    mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
 1:   1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1
 2:   1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1
 3:   1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    0
 4:   1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    0
 5:   1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1
 6:   1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    0
 7:   1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1
 8:   1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1
 9:   1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1
10:   1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1
11:   1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1
12:   1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1
13:   1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1
...
```